# Retrofit - null object after GET

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit

I would like to get all users from database and find user by login in list.
I always get info, that my actualUser is null. I try also show Log.d("msg", usr.getLogin()) but it's the same problem.

I have:

```
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
private User actualUser;

//Init API
Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
restAPI = retrofit.create(RESTAPInterface.class);

newDeviceAcceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //get user info
                getAllUsers();
                for(User usr: users){
                    if(UserCredentials.getInstance().getUsername().equals(usr.getLogin())) {
                        actualUser = new User(usr.getId(), usr.getLogin(), usr.getPassword());
                        Log.d("mojlogin", actualUser.getLogin());
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

and

```
public void getAllUsers(){
        compositeDisposable.add(restAPI.getUsers("Bearer " + TokenHolder.getInstance().getToken())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<User> users) throws Exception {
                initializeUsers(users);
            }
        }));
    }
```

and

```
public void initializeUsers(List<User> users){ this.users = users; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get actual user after call method of initializeUsers in getAllUsers.

like,

> ```
> public void getAllUsers(){
>     compositeDisposable.add(restAPI.getUsers("Bearer " + TokenHolder.getInstance().getToken())
>     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
>     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
>     .subscribe(new Consumer<List<User>>() {
>         @Override
>         public void accept(List<User> users) throws Exception {
>             Log.d("TAG", "users=>"+users.size());
>             initializeUsers(users);
>             for(User usr: users){
>                 if(UserCredentials.getInstance().getUsername().equals(usr.getLogin())) {
>                     actualUser = new User(usr.getId(), usr.getLogin(), usr.getPassword());
>                     Log.d("mojlogin", actualUser.getLogin());
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }));
> }
> ```

Comment: Why can’t I initialize users list by initializeUsers() metod?

Comment: You can initialize users list by initializeUsers() metod. Issue is actualUser return null due to get actualUser details before got response. So that you have to check actualUser after got response.

Comment: After used initializeUsers() I try display my users list in Log.d in onClick method. It’s also null.

Comment: Can you log the size of users before initializeUsers method? If users size is 0 or users are null return in response then first fix API call.

Comment: i update answer with log. Please check whether do you get size of user list or not after api call.

Comment: In `public void accept(List<User> users)` method my Object actualUser it's ok. But When i try use this actualUser bottom in onClick method after used getAllUsers() my actualUser object is null.

Comment: You are getting null actualUser object because actual user loop is execute before got response from getAllUsers() .

Comment: You are assign user list in initializeUsers method after get response. So actualUser will work after initializeUsers. If you will try to get actualUser after getAllUsers() in on click then it will return null. Because actualUser is called before got response and users list is null.